Unable to add repository to ArgoCD
We're currently trying to provision a High-Availability ArgoCD instance onto our Kubernetes cluster using the argocd helm chart (7.2.0) to provision our applications. Our infrastructure is on AWS and put together via AWS CDK written in TypeScript.
So far, we've managed to deploy the argocd helm chart using the following cdk snippet:
const argoCDHelmChart = this.cluster.addHelmChart('argocd-helmchart',
    {
        repository: 'https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm',
        chart: 'argo-cd',
        version: '7.2.0',
        namespace: 'argocd',
        release: 'argo-cd',
        values: {
            "redis-ha": { enabled: true },
            controller: {
                serviceAccount: { create: false },
                replicas: 1,
                envFrom: [{ secretRef: { name: 'proxy-config' }}]
            },
            server: {
                serviceAccount: { create: false },
                autoscaling: { enabled: false, minReplicas: 1 },
                envFrom: [{ secretRef: { name: 'proxy-config' }}]
            },
            repoServer: {
                autoscaling: { enabled: false, minReplicas: 1 },
                envFrom: [{ secretRef: { name: 'proxy-config' }}]
            },
            applicationSet: {
                replicas: 1,
                extraEnvFrom: [{ secretRef: { name: 'proxy-config' }}]
            },
        },
    }
)

However, when we try to add a repo to argocd with the following CLI command:
argocd repo add OUR_REPO_URL --server-name argo-cd-argocd-server --username OUR_USERNAME --password OUR_PASSWORD
We get the following error:
FATA[0000] rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\\r\\nContent-Length: 10\\r\\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\\r\\nDate: Thu, 25 Jul 2024 13:52:19 GMT\\r\\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\\r\\n\\r\\nForbidden\\n\""

We've already tried/validated the following:

All of our pods are healthy.
From the argocd-server/argocd-repo-server pods, with the same password and username combination we can reach our repo (git ls-remote / git clone works with the repo), so it's not a proxy or credentials issue.
When trying to add an App to ArgoCD, the app becomes healthy but the status on the UI shows the same error as from above (CLI)
We get the same error when we configure the argocd to take the GitHub repository configuration from the Kubernetes cluster's config-map

And if that helps anything, these are the argocd pods we've got in the cluster:

argo-cd-argocd-application-controller-0
argo-cd-argocd-applicationset-controller-885b744c4-v7pnv
argo-cd-argocd-dex-server-6f99bdb67d-tnf6c
argo-cd-argocd-notifications-controller-5869f85784-pdpll
argo-cd-argocd-redis-secret-init-vgkr6
argo-cd-argocd-repo-server-8679c8c796-69v2q
argo-cd-argocd-server-fcb9d7f76-9kk9j
argo-cd-redis-ha-haproxy-7fb5cb44cc-l4c8m
argo-cd-redis-ha-haproxy-7fb5cb44cc-twrkj
argo-cd-redis-ha-haproxy-7fb5cb44cc-vkqrm
argo-cd-redis-ha-server-0
argo-cd-redis-ha-server-1
argo-cd-redis-ha-server-2

All-in-all, we suspect that the argocd-server pod somehow cannot communicate/reach the argocd-repo-server pod.
Any pointers on what could be wrong here or how we could validate that the pods can even communicate with each other would be highly appreciated.

Try using this command:
argocd repo add OUR_REPO_URL  --name repo-name --insecure-ignore-host-key --ssh-private-key-path ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Make sure you run it from a machine with SSH configured that can access the repo. This will use the ssh key instead of a username/password, and has worked for me in the past while username/password always gave me access issues.
